# I need to make sure that I've used Bayes' Theorem correctly.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been doing some homework and I got very confused on Bayes' Theorem. Now that I think I understand it; I practiced it on a part of the assignment. I was hoping that someone could let me know if I did it correctly, so I know if I understand the formula finally.

The question (Part B):
[image]

My Solution (9.09%):
[image]

Comment: You should post your entire question here. It is possible to embed images into your post.

Comment: I tried adding in the images into the post, however it gives an error stating that I cannot.

Comment: I have added them.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e)

There are $10,000$ people in the community.

$20\%$ belong to party A -- $(10,000)(0.20) = 2,000$

$30\%$ of the members of party A are for the measure $(2,000)(0.30) = 600 = 6\%$ of the community belong to party A and support the measure.

For each party, how many members of the community belong to the party, and how many members of the community are both members of that party and for the measure.

$P(\text {Support the Measure}) = P(\text{Belong to A and Support the measure}) + P(\text{Belong to B and Support the measure}) + P(\text{Belong to C and Support the measure})$

When you have this you can proceed to f)

Probability that a supporter of the proposition is a member of party A.

$\frac {\text{Number of people who belong A and support the measure}}{\text{Number of people who support the measure}}$

Compare these results to the result you get using Bayes theorem

$P(\text{Belong to A}|\text {Support the measure}) = \frac {P(\text {Belong to A})}{P(\text {Support the Measure})} P(\text {Support the measure}|\text{Belong to A})$